# Error: Could not find truffle/Assert.sol from any sources;

Tags: truffle

I started a project with `truffle init`, and  I am trying to write a test and I have an import like so:

```
import "truffle/Assert.sol";
```

I get an error:

> Error: Could not find truffle/Assert.sol from any sources;

How do I fix this? Is `Assert` a built-in truffle library or do I have to install it separately?

Comment: this will help you this means a old issue,but some one solved: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/705

Answer (score 3):

Running `truffle test` from the command line should import the Assert.sol library if truffle was installed globally (using `npm install -g truffle`).

If truffle is globally installed, the "Assert.sol" file should be located in the directory

`C:\Users\[YourUsername]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build`

If things still don't work you could try copying the "Assert.sol" (and its imported dependencies, of which there's several) to your "contracts" folder and then importing it from there into your test contract.  But it's probably best to just get truffle installed globally and then use `truffle test`.